# Diffusing pressurized gas with minimum noise

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, gas

**Problem:**

I need to diffuse pressurized dry air (about 4-6 bar) in to a room, while creating minimal noise. The inner diameter of the tube is about 8 mm. Without a proper nozzle, there are bond to be vortexes and eddies screaming.

- Is there any kind of nozzle design already exist for this purpose ? For example, a firearm suppressor ?
- If possible, the nozzle should have minimum resistance to achieve maximum flow.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The device you seek is called a *muffler* and is in common use anywhere pressurized air has to be vented into a space with a minimum of noise. Suppliers of industrial compressed air fittings and equipment will have them for sale.